# Como hacer que funcione autenticación con AUTH0.com en Angular, cuando activas el {useHash: true} en las rutas de tu web

Tags: angular

gracias de antemano por el apoyo, estoy incorporando a mi web hecha con Angular la autenticación de (auth0.com) todos me funciona bien, pero al incorporar el acceso a una pagina web que usa el  {useHash: true} en el archivo de rutas no logro autenticar,  si desactivo {useHash: false} funciona bien bien localmente, pero al subir al hosting no se desplaza a las ruta de la web.

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.